# Run application multiple times that doesn't usually allow it. (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10

I'm trying to run an application multiple times, but this application does not usually work when ran multiple times, and will crash/close all of the other instances when a new instance is opened. What I'm trying to achieve is to somehow run this application multiple times. The application binds to port 2999, which means each instance would need its own ip. The application also needs to be able to use the gpu.

I've taken a look at Windows Sandbox, but I don't think there is a way I can create one programmatically and it also only allows one sandbox to be open at a time, which limits me to 2 per server.

I've also taken a look at Windows docker containers, but those don't allow any display output.
I've also tried using a linux Docker container with `wine` and x11docker but I kept getting a dll error from one of the dlls included in the directory of the application. (`stub.dll failed to initialize`)

Windows containers and Windows Sandbox from what I know don't support using the GPU either.

Running multiple VMs also won't work since I don't think there is a way I can allow each VM to share one gpu, and creating and starting a VM on-demand through a program would take too long.

I've tried running the application through different user accounts using the `runas` command, but that also didn't work.
I've tried changing the .exe filename thinking that maybe  it searches based on the exe name, but that also didn't work.

I've taken a look into sandboxie, and I don't think there's a cli for that and I wasn't able to get the game running in that.

Any help would be appreciated.
And if you're wondering what I'm trying to run. I'm trying to run the `League of Legends` **game** not client.

Comment: Seems like the better question to answer is why you need to run the same game, multiple times, simultaneously on one computer?

Comment: I'm trying to open multiple replay files, which normally can be opened through the client or by running the executable with the file as the first parameter. (ex: `"League of Legends.exe" "MyCoolReplay.rofl"`)

Answer (score 0):

You can run an application multiple times if you hold down the 'shift' key and click it, IF the developers allow it.
The restriction is not in Windows, its in the program itself.
If the developers of League of Legends have restricted it from being run multiple times on the one computer then its for a good reason.
Since LoL is an online game that requires an account, my guess is its so you can't run multiple instances with different logins and therefore gain an unfair advantage.
I assume this is what you're trying to do. It won't work.

Comment: I'm not looking to play the game online. The game is the only program that can fully decode game replay files and I'm looking to create a service that allows people to decode replay files into videos on devices that don't have the game installed.

Comment: I like your entrepreneurial spirit, but for the aforementioned reasons, it can't be done. At least, not without breaking the security.
And even if you did do it, LoL developers would shut you down.